# How to run multiple PHP scripts from CLI

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I have three different crawler scripts that I want to run in parallel and I'm wondering what command do I use to execute all three at the same time.

I'm on a nix platform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you're on a *nix platform, putting space ampersand ( & ) at the end of the command should put it in the background, giving you back your shell to run other commands. Obviously you want to make sure the output of the job goes to a file and not standard output (screen) or the output will get confusing between the various commands

Comment: When I use the space & it kills the previous script??

Comment: No, it sends it to a background process. Doing this does not effect any other processes.

Comment: Some of the details differ depending on the shell, but the basics are the same across sh, bash, ksh. Here's the top Google search I found for a tutorial. Google is your friend. http://kb.iu.edu/data/afnz.html

Comment: Looks like ubuntu does not allow you to run a PHP script in the background.

Answer (score 1):

An option is to run them in separate windows in screen. This will keep the output neatly compartmentalized, and you can disconnect from the screen leaving it in the background without interrupting the processes.

Comment: This is a little old, but I am looking for more details about your suggested solution.  I like the idea of using multiple windows, but how can I write a script that when ran automatically opens a new window for each process? Using ubuntu. Basically I would run this one .sh script and it would spawn the window for each of the php processes I want running simultaneously.

Comment: @user658182: Running the shell script from within a screen session and prefixing each line with `screen` should do the job.