# Executing multiple simultaneous php scripts from CLI

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I have 55 php files that I would like to run simultaneously from the command line. Right now, I am running them in multiple CLI windows using the code:

```
php Script1.php
```

I would like to be able to call one single php file that would execute all 55 php files simultaneously. I have been reading about how to make the command line not wait for the output, but I can't seem to make it work.

This thread:
[How to run multiple PHP scripts from CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313215/how-to-run-multiple-php-scripts-from-cli)

suggests putting an & at the end of the command to run the command in the background, but using the xampp CLI this doesn't seem to do anything.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Brian

Comment: What operating system are you running? When you refer to the "xampp CLI", is this basically a DOS prompt running in Windows? Also, could you provide some sample output -- basically copy and paste the command-line, showing the prompts, and what you've typed (and gotten in response)?

Comment: It's likely possible to run `php Script*.php`.

Comment: The `&` command is specific to Unix/Linux. On windows you might have a chance with `start` command.

Comment: @zneak: no. The php CLI interpreter will only run the first php file passed to it on the command line. Although some programs (e.g. vim) will process each argument - it does so serially, not in parallel. Similar for xargs.

Comment: @symcbean, I missed the simultaneous part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By mentioning XAMPP, I assume you are on windows. I think what you need is the `start` command. You probably need `start php Script1.php`. For more info, do a

```
start /?|more
```

Answer (score 2):

## Linux

Apart from adding a `&`, you also need to redirect output to somewhere - otherwise your php process waits until the other process finished, because there could be more output:

```
exec('/path/to/program & > /dev/null 2>&1')
```

Comment: Thanks, this will help when I go to my production server, but I don't think it works under xampp (windows).

Comment: does it have a different effect if we put the `&` at the end of the command?

Comment: try it, then tell us.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the php forking mechanism. Read about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php

Comment: Looked into it, but the solution below was a little easier and did what I needed. Thanks.